# "Face still", what's the meaning of "still" here?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-meaning

I would like to know what does "still" refers to exactly. I guess it has to do with movement. I have to translate this into Spanish and I don't know its particular meaning here: 
*"I have a year", she had said, **face still** and certain as the grave, full of a cold fire that Kate had never seen before*.

Could you tell me a synonym? 
Can it be similar to "blank face"? 
Or "serious"?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: serena, quieta, tranquila, inmóvil...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Still* is more normally used of, for example bodies of water of for people, rather than just faces, but it is not inappropriate in this rather poetic passage. It could be understood as it is defined in the first two entries  [here](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/still). My own suggestion for a word to translate would be *expressionless.*

.